# Constructor TextBook in class TextBook Cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a project that wants me to create 3 classes: TextBook, LibraryCard and Library and I need to put the TextBook Objects into the bookshelf array; I've already created the first 2 and they work fine, however, The library class is giving me this error:

```
Constructor TextBook in class TextBook cannot be applied to given types;
Required: java.lang.string
Found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here's the code for the textbook class:

```
public class TextBook
{

private String Title;
private int Chapters;
private int LastChapter;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class TextBook
 */
public TextBook(String Titlename, int Chapters_init)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    Title = Titlename;
    Chapters = Chapters_init;
    LastChapter = 0;

}


public String getTitle()
{
    return Title;
}

public void readNextChapter()
{
    for(LastChapter=0;LastChapter<Chapters;LastChapter++) {
        System.out.println("You have finished the book!");
    }
}

public boolean isfinished()
{
    if (LastChapter == Chapters)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public void closeBook()
{
    LastChapter = 0;
}

public void describe()
{
    System.out.println("You are currently Reading " + Title); 
}
```

and here is the code for the library class:

```
public class Library
{
 int nextBook;
 int borrowers = 0;

public Library(int Max_Books)
{
    TextBook[] bookshelf = new TextBook[5];
    for(int ptr=0;ptr<bookshelf.length;ptr++)
        bookshelf[ptr] = new TextBook();
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is confusing about the error? you call `new TextBook()` but the constructor takes a string and an int

Comment: Your constructor for `TextBook` is defined as `public TextBook(String Titlename, int Chapters_init)`. That means you must call it like this `new TextBook("Book title goes here", 25);`.  If you call it without arguments, like this, `new TextBook()`, you will get the error you described.  You could add a no argument constructor if you'd like to instantiate one without a title and number of chapters.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you so much that worked, I'm sorry I'm just new to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of TextBook, by calling the default constructor.

In your class, you have defined a constructor with a signature that expects a String and an int.

A default constructor would be:

```
public TextBook() {
    // body
}
```

So either you add this constructor above to your code, or you use your existing constructor correctly by providing it with the required parameters.